# WPF Progress Bar in New Window

Tags: c#, wpf, progress-bar

I'm new for WPF. Now, I have to make a progressbar in a new window from my main window, but I don't know how to make it run the progress in new window.

Below is my declaration in mainwindow.xaml.cs:

```
   progressWnd = new ProgressDownloadWindow(cnt_s);
   progressWnd.Owner = this;
   progressWnd.ShowDialog();
   foreach (var dl in this.dldatagrid.SelectedItems)
   {
        string fileName = dl.path;
        this.Download(fileName, false, date);
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

The `ProgressBar` exposes a property called `Value`, which you can use to set the value of the progressbar. So you would need to to something like

```
foreach (var dl in this.dldatagrid.SelectedItems)
{ 
    string fileName = dl.path;
    this.Download(fileName, false, date);
    progressbar.Value++;
}
```

Apart from that, your system won't work as you are using `ShowDialog()` which creates a modal dialog and the parent window will block.
So you would need to create the window with a new `Dispatcher` and run it on another thread to have it work while you do your downlods.

Look on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.progressbar.aspx) for reference.